# postcss-extract-media-query plugin is invalid

Tags: css, media-queries, postcss, webpack-3, postcss-loader

I'm trying to extract some media queries from my css bundles, but unfortunately plugin is not working.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./node_modules/jscrollpane/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css
    Module build failed: TypeError: Invalid PostCSS Plugin found at: plugins[0]
```

Here is my **postcss.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        {
            'postcss-extract-media-query': {
                output: {
                    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
                    name: '[name]-[query].[ext]'
                },
                queries: {
                    'screen and (min-width: 1024px)': 'desktop'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Postcss works fine without it, at least I don't have any errors

Part of **webpack.config.js**, I doubt I have any problems here since it works fine

```
cssLoader = [ 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],

return {
    module: {
        rules: [ { test: /\.css$/, use:  cssLoader  },]
    }
}
```

Part of my **package.json**

```
    "postcss": "^7.0.14",
    "postcss-extract-media-query": "^1.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.12.0",
```

Do you have any idea why it's not working?

**UPD:**

I don't have any errors if I will use it as follows:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
            require('postcss-extract-media-query'),
    ] }
```

But I need to set up some options as well, so it's not working for me